# PHP - Parsing text for a specific occurencies

Tags: php, domdocument, domxpath

I am working on a code which is giving me an output source of URL.
Then when I have this output, I parse an javascript text.
Here is the text which I am parsing: http://pastebin.com/7yZ9RqJa

Here is my code:

```
<?PHP
$url = 'http://www.sportsdirect.com/dunlop-mens-canvas-low-top-trainers-246046?colcode=24604622';
libxml_use_internal_errors(true); 
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile($url);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

$DataVariants = $xpath->query('//span[@class="ImgButWrap"]/@data-variants')->item(0)->nodeValue;

$jsonStart = strpos($DataVariants, '[');
$jsonEnd = strrpos($DataVariants, ']');

$collections = json_decode(substr($DataVariants, $jsonStart, $jsonEnd - $jsonStart + 1));

foreach ($collections as $item) {
    $ColVarId = $item->ColVarId;
    $SizeNames = $item->SizeVariants->SizeName;

    echo "$ColVarId - $SizeNames ,<br>";
}

?>
```

This is giving me the result like:

```
24604603 - , 
24604684 - , 
24604640 - ,
24604609 - , 
24604682 - , 
24604686 - , 
24604681 - , 
24604689 - , 
24604602 - , 
24604679 - , 
24604680 - , 
24604622 - , 
24604685 - , 
24604683 - , 
24604621 - , 
24604677 - , 
24604688 - ,
```

So with this code I used to get all the `ColVarId`s. 
In addition to that I want to get all `SizeName` for a specific `ColVarId`.

For example I want to get all `SizeName` ids for `ColVarId` = 24604603 .

Is it possible and how I can make that ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your loop to read size names to next:

```
foreach ($collections as $item) {
    $ColVarId = $item->ColVarId;

    $SizeNames = [];
    foreach ($item->SizeVariants as $size) {
        $SizeNames[] = $size->SizeName;
    }
    $names = implode(',', $SizeNames);

    echo "$ColVarId - $names ,<br>";
}
```

Also I think before add **$size->SizeName** value to **$SizeNames** array better test if it is real/not empty size.

Answer (score 0):

SizeVariants is also an array, so you cannot access SizeName property of the array, you have to specify which element of that array you want to get SizeName.

```
$SizeNames = $item->SizeVariants
foreach ($SizeNamesas $sn)
{
echo $sn->SizeName;
}
```

This is how you access the SizeName.
If you want to access all SizeNames of a specific ColVarId, you can check that inside your foreach.

```
$myColVarId = 24604603;
foreach ($collections as $item) {

    $ColVarId = $item->ColVarId;
    if($ColVarId == $myColVarId){
        $SizeNames = $item->SizeVariants
        foreach ($SizeNamesas $sn)
        {
              echo "$ColVarId".'-'.$sn->SizeName;
        }
    }
    else
    continue; //this item does not have our ColVarId, so we skip.
}


    $SizeNames = $item->SizeVariants->SizeName;

    echo "$ColVarId - $SizeNames ,<br>";
}
```

The code is not tested.